# Synchronization on ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

In my application I am using a ConcurrentHashMap and I need this type of "custom put-if-absent" method to be executed atomically.

```
public boolean putIfSameMappingNotExistingAlready(String key, String newValue) {
    String value;
    synchronized (concurrentHashMap) {
    if (value = concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(key, newValue)) == null) {
          // There was no mapping for the key
      return true;
      } else { if (value.equals(newValue)) {
                // The mapping <key, newValue> already exists in the map
                return false;
            } else {
                concurrentHashMap.put(key, newValue);
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
    }
```

I read (in the concurrent package documentation) that

> A concurrent collection is thread-safe, but not governed by a single exclusion lock.

So you can not get an exclusive lock on a ConcurrentHashMap.

My questions are:

1. Is the code above thread-safe? To me it looks like it is guaranteed that the code in the synchronized block can be executed only by a single thread at the same time, but I want to confirm it.
2. Wouldn't it be "cleaner" to use Collections.synchronizedMap() instead of ConcurrentHashMap in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it really 'concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(msg, msg)'?

Comment: Can you use a compare-and-set loop instead of a lock? http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Comment: @ovdsrn Your code suggested in EDIT won't work as putIfAbsent does nothing if there is already a mapping for this key.

Comment: @isnot2bad You are perfectly right, stupid me, I will delete the edit since it makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

The following code uses a compare-and-set loop (as suggested by SlakS) to implement thread safety (Note the infinite loop):

```
/**
 * Updates or adds the mapping for the given key.
 * Returns true, if the operation was successful and false,
 * if key is already mapped to newValue.
 */
public boolean updateOrAddMapping(String key, String newValue) {
    while (true) {
        // try to insert if absent
        String oldValue = concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
        if (oldValue == null) return true;

        // test, if the values are equal
        if (oldValue.equals(newValue)) return false;

        // not equal, so we have to replace the mapping.
        // try to replace oldValue by newValue
        if (concurrentHashMap.replace(key, oldValue, newValue)) return true;

        // someone changed the mapping in the meantime!
        // loop and try again from start.
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't know with your suggestion if the mapping <key, value> is already in the map. You will be able to figure out only if there was or not a mapping for the key.

Comment: Note, if Java 7, `nullSafeEquals()` can be replaced with `Objects.equals()`

Comment: @fge Fine. Was not sure if it is Java 7 or 8.

Comment: +1 The only comment I will make is that `concurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent` will acquire a lock each time which may decrease throughput if there are many `replace` or `Object.equals` invocations going on.  I would get `oldValue` first then if it's null doing a putItAbsent test (while re-assigning oldValue).

Comment: @JohnVint I removed `get` completely by using the return value of `putIfAbsent` instead. (In case the entry already exists, `putIfAbsent` should work like `get` concerning throughput). Code is simpler now.

Answer (score 0):

By synchronizing on the entire collection like that you are essentially replacing the fine-grained synchronization within the concurrent collection with your own blunt-force approach.

If you aren't using the concurrency protections elsewhere then you could just use a standard `HashMap` for this and wrap it in your own synchronization. Using a `synchronizedMap` may work, but wouldn't cover multi-step operations such as above where you put, check, put.